# Can't use [FromQuery] and OData at the same time in ASP.NET 6

Tags: asp.net, rest, routes, odata

I am quite a newbie in building ASP.NET Web Apis (so I apologise in advance if this questions seems a silly one) and the moment came for me to adopt OData in order to have more complex queries.
I have followed a basic guide and configured OData like this in my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddOData(options =>
    options.EnableQueryFeatures(null))
```

Then, I simply decorated the methods needing OData queries with `[EnableQuery]` attribute and everything seemed to work quite fairly. I have been able to order, skip and take whatever I wanted, until when I introduced this new method:

```
    [HttpGet("AllFiltered")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllFilteredAsync([FromQuery] Enums.MyEnum[]? filters, [FromQuery] string? userId = null)
    {
        return Ok(await _myCustomManager.GetAllFilteredAsync(filters, userId));
    }
```

which already has his own filters. Then I tried to add OData filters like this:

> https://mybackend.net/api/MyTable/AllFiltered?filters=-1&filters=0?$orderby=Date%20desc&skip=0&top=15

but I unfortunately get this error:

> {"errors":{"filters":["The value '0?$orderby=Date desc' is not valid."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-22acad363a347b307ff4cb3d7f88b7d4-cab5bb7b8e1c9e9c-00"}

thus suggesting this syntax can't be used. Is there a way I can achieve what I want without using the `$filter` feature of OData?
If this method I'm using is not the best practice in managing the matter, would you please suggest a better one?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understand now, so is it just by chance that without any schema that attribute allowed me to order and take same data with OData until now? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core 6. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: That `?` in `filters=0?$orderby=Date%20desc` should be `&`. Without this, the entire value up to skip is treated as a single value. Have you tried using `https://mybackend.net/api/MyTable/AllFiltered?filters=-1&filters=0&$orderby=Date%20desc&skip=0&top=15` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @PanagiotisKanavos! You saved me! Now I finally understand how to properly use both the parameters I need in the Uri and the OData features that need to be used later! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

That `?` in `filters=0?$orderby=Date%20desc` must be `&`, thus introducing OData parameters as additional parameters. Without this, the entire value up to `skip` is treated as a single value and you get a validation error.